# Is it required to link in all dependencies?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, ld

Let's say we have a library libutils which implements two functions: function1 and function2. And let's say function2 uses library libanother (so libutils depends on libanother).

Now I want to build my application that uses function1 only:

```
g++ myapplication.cpp -o my application -lutils
```

Is it required to include libanother in linkage:

```
g++ myapplication.cpp -o my application -lutils -lanother
```

Is there any linker requirements concerning that? Does the answer depend on whether the libraries libutils and libanother are shared or static?

Answer (score 2):

**Some first principles**

Three kinds of files can be input to the linkage of a program:

- object files
- static libraries
- shared libraries

But only *two* of those kinds of files can actually be *linked* into the program:
object files and shared libraries.<sup>1</sup>

If you input any *object* file `p.o` to the linkage of a program the linker
links it into the program *unconditionally*.

If you input a [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) `libx.a` to the your linkage, the linker *extracts* from `libx.a` each archive member
`libx.a(q.o)` that it *needs* to carry on the linkage and links *it* into
the program. An archive member `libx.a(q.o)` is *needed* if it defines at least one
symbol that has been referenced, but not yet defined, in some file (object file or
shared library) that has already been linked into the program.

If you input a shared library `liby.so`, the story forks:-

- If the linker (`ld`) option `--as-needed` is in effect when `liby.so` is reached,
  then `liby.so` will be linked into the program if it is *needed* in the same sense as an archive member `libx.a(q.o)`.
- If `--as-needed` is *not* in effect, then `liby.so` is linked unconditionally, like
  an object file.

If you invoke the linker via one of your distro's GCC frontends (`gcc`, `g++`, `gfortran`...) in the usual
way, then you will always get the `--as-needed` behaviour for shared libraries by default, or always not get it, as long as your
GCC toolchain remains the same, because your distro's build of GCC will configure `--as-needed`
as a default linkage option, or not, according to that distro's appraisal of the pros and cons of doing so.
Debian-derived distros (Ubuntu et al.) have defaulted to `--as-needed` in recent years. Last time I looked,
Redhat-derived distros (Fedora et al.) did not.<sup>2</sup>

When any file `file.{o|so}` is linked into the program it introduces 0 or more *unresolved references* into the program. Those unresolved references are
references to symbols in `file.{o|so}` that are not defined in `file.{o|so}` or in any other file already linked into the program.

The linker must resolve all references by the time it has finished the linkage of the
program, or the linkage fails with unresolved reference errors. Files must be input and linked that provide definitions for
all of the symbols that are *referenced in the files that are linked*.

**Down to your case**

When you say:

> my application ... uses function1 only

you mean that some file *will* be linked that references `function1`. It's simple
to assume this file is some object file that will be linked unconditionally,
say the one that defines `main`, e.g.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void function1(void);

void call_function1(void) {
    function1();
}

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!");
}
```

which we compile to an object file:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c
```

Notice that `main.o` references `function1` despite the fact that we cannot
run a program with that `main` function in any way that will *call*
`function1`. `main.o` defines a function,
`call_function1`, that calls `function1`; so `function1` is referenced in `main.o`.
`call_function1` is *not* referenced itself, but `function1` is. If we look at
the symbol table of `main.o`:

```
$ nm main.o
0000000000000000 T call_function1
                 U function1
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000000000000000c T main
                 U puts
```

the symbols annotated `T` are defined. The ones annotated `U` are referenced
but not defined. So when we try to link `main.o` into a program:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `call_function1':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `function1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

we need to input a file that defines `function1`, even though a program linked
with this `main.o` cannot possibly call `function1`.

Your `function1` is defined, somehow, within a library `libutils`, which also
defines `function2`. Your program does not reference `function2`, but
the definition of `function2` references one or more symbols, say `function3`, that are defined,
somehow, within another library `libanother`.

Do you need to add `libanother`, as well as `libutils` to the linkage of your
program?

From first principles, we know you must add `libanother` to your linkage if you link a file that references `function3`.
`function3` is referenced in the definition of `function2`. So you must link with `libanother`
if you link a file that contains the definition of `function2`.

*Do you need to link such a file?*

That depends on the implementation of `libutils` itself.

**Case 1**

Suppose you have implemented `libutils` as a static library in which you have
archived an object file that defines `function1` and another object file that
defines `function2`. Like so:

**function1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**function2.c**

```
extern void function3();

void function2(void)
{
    function3();
}
```

Compile the source files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c function1.c function2.c
```

Archive the object files:

```
$ ar rcs libutils.a function1.o function2.o
```

Link `prog` like:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libutils.a
```

No problem. Run:

```
$ ./prog
Hello World!
```

Let's do the linkage again, this time with diagnostics to show what
object files and shared libraries were actually linked:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libutils.a -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o
main.o
(libutils.a)function1.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
(//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Most of those inputs are boilerplate object files and shared libraries that
`gcc` adds to program linkage by default. The files that *we* built are just:

```
main.o
(libutils.a)function1.o
```

The archive member `libutils.a(function2.o)` wasn't linked at all, because
no file was linked that references `function2`. So it doesn't matter that
`libutils.a(function2.o)` makes an undefined reference to `function3`. `libutils.a(function2.o)`
might as well not exist. The linkage:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libutils.a
```

is exactly the same linkage as:

```
gcc -o prog main.o function1.o
```

**Case 2**

Suppose you've implemented `libutils` as a static library that contains
one object file that defines both `function1` and `function2`:

**function12.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

extern void function3(void);

void function2(void)
{
    function3();
}
```

Compile that file:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c function12.c
```

Recreate `libutils.a`:

```
$ rm libutils.a
$ ar rcs libutils.a function12.o
```

Relink `prog`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libutils.a -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o
main.o
(libutils.a)function12.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
(//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: libutils.a(function12.o): in function `function2':
function12.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `function3'
/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `prog'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This time, as the `-trace` output shows, our object files:

```
main.o
(libutils.a)function12.o
```

were linked. `main.o` referenced `function1`, so the linker searched `libutils.a`
for an object file that defines `function1`. It found `function12.o` and linked
it, including the definition of `function2` as well as the definition of `function1`.
The definition of `function2` introduced an unresolved reference to `function3`,
into the program. No file was linked that resolved that reference, so the
linkage failed:

```
function12.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `function3'
```

It doesn't matter that `function2` cannot be *called* by the program -
just like it doesn't matter that `function1` cannot be called.<sup>3</sup>

**Case 3**

You have implemented `libutils` as a *shared* library, by linking position-independent
object files `function1.o` and `function2.o` compiled from `function1.c` and `function2.c`
respectively:

```
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c function1.c function2.c
$ gcc -shared -o libutils.so function1.o function2.o
```

Notice here that although the shared library `libutils.so` is an ELF file produced
by *linkage* (not an `ar` archive of object files), we are able to link it successfully
despite the fact that `function2.o` contains an undefined reference to `function3`.

It is fine to link a shared library with undefined references. See its symbol table:

```
$ nm libutils.so
0000000000004030 b completed.7930
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001060 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000010d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003e18 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004028 d __dso_handle
0000000000003e20 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000001150 t _fini
0000000000001110 t frame_dummy
0000000000003e10 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000000020f0 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000002020 r __func__.2361
0000000000001115 T function1
0000000000001142 T function2
                 U function3
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
000000000000202c r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001090 t register_tm_clones
```

There is `U function3`. But you can't link a *program* with undefined references:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libutils.so -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o
main.o
libutils.so
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
(//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: libutils.so: undefined reference to `function3'
/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `prog'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When we link:

```
main.o
libutils.so
```

the linkage fails just as with:

```
main.o
(libutils.a)function12.o
```

or indeed:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o function1.o function2.o
/usr/bin/ld: function2.o: in function `function2':
function2.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `function3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So:

> Is it required to link in all dependencies?

Yes, when you're linking a *program*. But understand what *the dependencies* of
a program are:

The dependencies of the program are *object files* and/or *shared libraries*
that define the symbols that are referenced in the object files and shared libraries
that are actually linked.

A static library is never one those. It is a container of object files from which
the linker will extract and link ones that *are* dependencies of the program and ignore
the rest.

---

[1] What the linker *does* to link an object file into a program is fundamentally
different from what it does to link a shared library.

Roughly, to link an object file, it physically merges the parts of which the object
file is composed into the corresponding parts of the output program.

Roughly, to link a shared library `liby.so`, the linker just writes some concise information in
a standard format into the program that will be parsed by the runtime loader,
instructing it to find and load `liby.so` and merge the parts of which it is
composed into the process of the executed program.

[2] You can check whether your GCC toolchain defaults to `--as-needed` or not
by grepping for that option in the verbose output of a default GCC linkage, e.g.

```
$ gcc -v -o prog main.o function1.o 2>&1 | grep '\--as-needed'
```

[3] We *can* compile object files with a non-default compilation option [`-ffunction-sections`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)
and link them in programs with a non-default linker option [`-gc-sections`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html), with the
effect that the linker will be able to *discard* definitions of functions that
cannot called, so that they cannot give rise to any references that impose useless
dependencies on the program.

Comment: Three additional options to consider for a tidy link are `-fdata-sections`, `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` and `-Wl,--as-needed`. `-Wl,--as-needed` can often remove unneeded libraries like `-lm`.

Answer (score 0):

If no call made from second library, it is not required. Typically linker will give error if function in linking for which library or its definition is not present during linking as undefined.